# Parsing html with SAX parser

Tags: java, html, parsing, sax

I am trying to parse the normal html file using SAX parser.

```
SAXBuilder builder2 = new SAXBuilder();
         try {
            Document sdoc = (Document)builder2.build(readFile);
            NodeList nl=sdoc.getElementsByTagName("body");
            System.out.println("nodelist>>>>>>>>>>>"+nl.getLength());

        } catch (JDOMException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but i am getting the  exception

```
Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "class".
```

can anyone please tell me why i am getting this exception, the html document is well formed and it has all the open and close tags properly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to do this with SAX?

Comment: No, just want to fetch the body content from the html file, So, i used it. Is there any other solution?

Comment: With SAX you could parse XHTML, but I'm not sure if it can also parse HTML (at least most XML parser don't). HTML doesn't have to be a well-formed XML.

Answer (score 6):

As flash says, you need an HTML parser, not an XML parser. HTML is not XML.

Good parsers i've used are [Neko](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/) and [TagSoup](http://vrici.lojban.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/). Neko is a good all-round parser; TagSoup specifically aims to be able to parse anything, no matter how ill-formed.

Comment: The thing about TagSoup is that, being based on SAX, it's lightning fast and it solves all the stuff basic SAX chokes on including &lt; and &gt;. It's as easy to set up for as SAX; the handler methods are just the same ones--no learning curve beyond the SAX you already know.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, you cannot parse HTML with an XML parser:

- HTML's element tags are not required to match in all cases.  (For example a `<p>` tag does not require a matching `</p>` tag.)  This will cause terminal indigestion for an XML parser.
- Real-world HTML is notorious for not being conformant to the HTML spec, let alone an XML compatible subset of HTML.

However, if your input document is XHTML, you should *in theory* be able to use an XML parser such as SAX.  You *should* even be able to validate the document against the XHTML schema.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at [HtmlParser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/). Normally SAX is not a good solution to parse html.

Comment: SAX is always a good option for parsing huge amounts of data - such as HTML. Try looking at TagSoup which is quite awesome for doing just that!

Answer (score -1):

Another HTML parser for Java is JSoup: https://jsoup.org/